# How to identify master page and page layout of a page?

Tags: master-page

How to identify which master page and page layout the page is made from?

I have a page and I need to apply some content marking on it. I am not able to identify where exactly I need to do so, for all the other pages I did it from the visual studio. But for this particular page, it is not there in the visual studio project.The page is a wiki page.

Note: I am using SP 2010.

Comment: for which SharePoint version you are looking? Please add some more content to your question to make it more digestible.

Comment: I am using SP 2010. 
Description:
I need to add content marking on the footer of the webpage.The footer part  of the page is coming from the master page. The content marking such as author name, help URLs and the type and other parameters of the page are coming form the fields of page library.
To edit the page and add more content markings on the footer, changes have to be made on the page layouts which are in solution made to apply the master page and pagelayouts. All pages except one are made with these page layouts. That 1 exceptional page is a wiki page which my question is about.

Comment: How do I change the footer of a wiki page? The footer part of the wiki page is from the master page. I need to append the content marking (<Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl FieldName="Marking" runat="server" controlMode="Display">) on the foooter of the wiki page, this marking will come from a field which will be fetched from the page library.

Comment: In that case, if you have permission to update the system masterpage, you can update that and add footer content in it.

Comment: If I change the system master page, the changes will be applied to all the system pages. I want my changes to be reflected on just the desired wiki pages.

Comment: Then you can add your DOM content only if it matches current page wiki page URL with the help of JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have created a separate master page with the desired contents and attached it to the desired wiki pages through SP Designer.

Answer (score 2):

For SharePoint 2010 and 2013, you can use PowerShell to find this information.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$site = Get-SPSite http://siteurl
$web = $site.RootWeb
$web.CustomMasterUrl
```

This will return the path to the master page being used, relative to the hive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am using SP 2010. Will this script give the master page for the specific page or the whole web / site?

Comment: How do I change the footer of a wiki page?

The footer part of the wiki page is from the master page. I need to append the content marking (<Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl FieldName="Marking" runat="server" controlMode="Display">) on the foooter of the wiki page, this marking will come from a field which will be fetched from the page library.